# Change shelves into separate columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, automation, spreadsheet

Every day I have an inventory to do. 100 or so items on 15 or so shelves.  I also have an xml report that shows what should be available in the room - but this xml does not show what shelves the items should be on. Currently I scan the items and if it is all in the room, fantastic.  If it is not in the room, i am aware and go hunt it down.  In some cases, it is just on the wrong shelf, but I would have no way to know. . .

The idea I had was to scan a barcode assigned to a shelf, then scan the items.  then have the report bump against the scanned column.  Problem is that this creates a single column in excel.

I am open to ideas on how to do this.  I am obviously lost.

I was thinking of telling excel to automatically split the data into separate columns?  All shelf 'headers' are only 5 alphanumeric characters long .  all items have 7 alphanumeric characters long.

Original Output

| Column A |
| --- |
| AAAAA |
| 1XXXXXX |
| 1XXXXXY |
| 3XXXXXX |
| BBBBB |
| 1XXXXXX |
| CCCCC |
| 3YYYYYY |

Desired Output (I am open to any ideas)

| Shelf | Item |
| --- | --- |
| AAAAA | 1XXXXXX |
| AAAAA | 1XXXXXY |
| AAAAA | 3XXXXXX |
| BBBBB | 1XXXXXX |
| CCCCC | 3YYYYYY |

then I was thinking of some how telling excel to match the two sheets (or sections, it can be on the same sheet), and identify anything missing from the room, or identify anything on the wrong shelf.

The report showing what is 'in the room' looks like this.  This report has multiple columns, but column B and Column E has the related data.

| Column B | Column E |
| --- | --- |
| AAAAA | 1XXXXXX |
| AAAAA | 1XXXXXY |
| AAAAA | 3XXXXXX |
| BBBBB | 1XXXXXX |
| CCCCC | 3YYYYYY |

I am thinking that once the format is the same, it will be easy to highlight anything that is different. again, I am open to any ideas.  Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This task is quickly and easily solved using the **Power Query** tool, which is located on the Data tab.

If your version of Excel does not have this tool or you do not have the skills to use it, then you can solve the problem the old fashioned way, using formulas from standard Excel functions.

Put in cells `B1:D1` column headings, for example, **Shelf** - **Item** - **Availability**

In cell **B2** formula `=IF(C2="";A1;B1)`

In cell **C2** formula `=IF(LEN(TRIM(A1))=7;A1;"")`

In cell **D2** formula

`=IF(C2="";"";IF(SUMPRODUCT(N(Sheet2!$B:$B=B2);N(Sheet2!$E:$E=C2));"Present";"Not present"))`

Stretch down to end of data